# Find the number of ways of choosing three initials from the alphabet if none of the letters can be repeated

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

This question is from Marcel Finan A Probability Course for the Actuaries
A Preparation for Exam P/1

4.8 Find the number of ways of choosing three initials from the alphabet if none of the letters can be repeated. Name initials such as MBF and BMF are
considered different.

Now I have a solution so I will write an answer but I want to know if its the correct logic and method to solving the problem.

I am studying to take the P Exam for actuaries so this is not homework, but independent study.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are 26 letters for the first initial then 25 other options for the second and 24 for the third. Thus the answer is $26\times 25\times 24=15600$

If we consider initials to be the same if they use the same set of letters (I.e ABC is the same as BAC) then for each set of initials we counted in the first part there would be 5 others that are the same (as all the letters are different) thus we would split them up into groups of the form (ABC, ACB, BAC, BCA, CAB, CBA) so we just divide the result by 6 to get 2600

Comment: What happens if you start in second position or third.  According to you $ABC = BAC$.

Comment: Suppose our alphabet is only 3 letters (A,B,C). Then my formula would give 6 different possibilities for initials which you can easily check on paper must require $ABC\ne BAC$. This is because I just choose any old first letter and my only condition for the second is that it can't be the same as the first (hence only 25 choices) and so on.

Comment: If $ABC=BAC$ how would one find the answer?

Comment: I updated my answer